# Ionic 3 dismiss modal and navigate is hiding tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem where when I call **this.viewCtrl.dismiss();** and **this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);** in my function, the tabs at the bottom of the page disappear

So I have 3 pages/modal:
page1: home page, page2: modal, page3: second page

I navigate from my home page to the modal which has two actions(accept or reject)

If the user accepts then go to the second page, if the use rejects then go back to the home page. When the user accepts everything works as expected however if the user rejects then the app hides the tabs at the bottom of the page

My code for the reject button navigation is as follows

**Modal page**

```
  gotoHome(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  }
```

**Second page**

calling modal in constructor

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public storage: Storage) {
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(modal);
    myModal.present();
  }
```

My TabsPage is default as per Ionics Tabs Layout App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to push the homepage from the modal since, you said, you are going back to homepage.

Change in `modal.ts`

```
gotoHome(){
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
}
```

to

```
accepted: boolean;

....

accept(){
    this.accepted = true;
    this.dismiss();
}

reject(){
    this.accepted = false;
    this.dismiss();
}

dismiss(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.accepted);
}
```

Call the `accept()` when accepted and `reject()` when rejected

Handle your actions after dismissing view by

```
let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(modal);
myModal.onDidDismiss( accepted => {

  // your actions here
  console.log(accepted);   

  if(accepted){
      this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage);
  }

});
myModal.present();
```

I created an example here on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-return-data?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: this fixes the tabs disappearing problem however If I click accept on the modal it now also goes back to the home page

Comment: how about when you press accept or reject, you set a value on a variable and pass it on view dismiss. Then push the page depending on that variable. See the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

Comment: I edited my answer and provided an example on stackblitz